# Is Broly Super Saiyan 4 a regular Super Saiyan 4 transformation or does it have something "Legendary" and different from the others Super Saiyan 4?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

Broly in Dragon Ball Heroes turns into Super Saiyan 4, but before that he has a "legendary super saiyan" transformation others saiyans don't have, and also he has a red aura instead of yellow, though this could mean he's in the limit breaker Super Saiyan 4 form .

[image]

Is Broly Super Saiyan 4 a regular Super Saiyan 4 transformation or does it have something "Legendary" and different from the others Super Saiyan 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Dragon Ball Wiki - Legendary Super Sayan 4](https://dragonballaffanon.fandom.com/wiki/Legendary_Super_Saiyan_4)

> Broly's Super Saiyan 4 form is largely similar to Goku's Super Saiyan
> 4 form, although the main difference is his having a significantly
> built frame and blank eyes (similar to his Legendary Super Saiyan
> state). It also has a yellow aura when in use, and is one of the few
> Legendary variants to not have Broly possess emerald hair.

[image]

> The Legendary Super Saiyan 4 form, like Legendary Super Saiyan 3 and
> Legendary Great Ape, is only seen in video games. Broly is shown
> attaining this form thanks to assistance from Black Smoke Shenron, who
> uses his shadows to transform Broly into a Super Saiyan 4 in the JM7
> trailer for Dragon Ball Heroes, and then proceeded to fight and nearly
> kill Super Saiyan 4 Goku and Vegeta, and Super Saiyan 3 Beat but was
> struggling against Super Saiyan 2 Note before Super Pikkon arrived.

Broly Super Saiyan 4 is different from other Super Saiyan 4 transformations as it was attained through the negative energy from the Cracked Dragon Balls and Black Smoke Shenron.

[image]

> The red aura is present at Super Sayan 4 Full Power which is more
> powerful than the Super Saiyan 4 form, seemingly a combination of the
> former and Legendary Super Saiyan. Broly attained this form around the
> Assault on the Hell Gate Saga and used it to defeat the Time Breaker
> leaders.